# ajax post works when function is in the route, but return error 500 when route to function in controller

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

I'm trying to post ajax in laravel 5, but when i have the function in the controller it works fine but when i try to link to controller, it return error 500 (Internal Server Error)

my JS

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
    }
});

$.ajax({
        url: 'myLink',
        type: "post",
        data: {
            'start': start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
            'end': end.format('YYYY-MM-DD')
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function(){ 
            alert("error!!!!");
        }
    });
```

My route (non working)

```
Route::post('/admin/getStoreIncome',  'Admin@method');
```

My route (working)

```
Route::post('/admin/getStoreIncome',  function()
{
    if(Request::ajax()) {
            $data = Input::all();
            print_r($data);die;
        }
});
```

My Controller

```
public function method() {
        if(Request::ajax()) {
            $data = Input::all();
            print_r($data);die;
        }
    }
```

Namespace i use for my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
```

Am i doing something wrong here?  Do i need a session namespace for the csrf? If someone have experience with this please help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure my answer will help you, But Through Jquery I have Done

I have a DropDown OnChange I am sending selected Value in My Controller and Then I am getting the response on my view Page

```
    (function($) {
           $('#bath').on('change', function() {
              var optionSelected = $(this).find("option:selected");
              var prop_type = optionSelected.val();

            $.ajax({
                   type: "GET",
                   url: "baths", //my Controller Function
                   dataType: "json",
                   data: {baths: prop_type},
                   success:function(row)
                {
                     $('#getRequestdata').empty('clear').html(row.html);
                }
             }); 
         });

    })(jQuery);
```

I hope it will help you!!!

Comment: I found my error.  I did not use request facade and trying to call Request::ajax().  Fixed it include request facade namespace and everything fixed

Comment: ohh you are correct before making any request to ajax  you must have to include Request Facade..